# Error establishing a database connection in my localhost

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to install Wordpress in my localhost Xampp server

But every time I got an error message with

> error establishing database connection.
>
> This either means that the username and password information in your
> wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database
> server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is
> down.

I have already googling but not get the correct answer yet.

I add `define( 'WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true );` in wp-config.php but not solved.......

Comment: Did you create the database BEFORE attempting the WP Install?

Comment: RiggsFolly...Yes I have created the database

Comment: Double check DB name, user and password especially last one if you changed it in xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my error as below procedure.

While installing Wordpress in localhost, first set some credentials of the file `wp-config-sample.php` as below

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define( 'DB_NAME', 'learn_wordpress' );

/** MySQL database username */
define( 'DB_USER', 'root' );

/** MySQL database password */
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );

/** MySQL hostname */
define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost' );
```

and save the file name as `wp-config.php` and run again `localhost/wordpress` in the url.

It's done !!

Comment: This is literally a copy and paste of what I told you you to do.

Answer (score 9):

This means wordpress can't find your database.

Navigate to http://localhost/phpmyadmin. Where it says create new database, choose a name for your database.

Next, open up wp-config.php in the root of your wordpress folder, and update the four values shown below to reflect your new database.

The default credentials for your newly created database are:

1. DB_NAME: Your chosen db name (case sensitive)
2. DB_USERNAME: root
3. DB_PASSWORD: ""
4. DB_HOST: localhost

```
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', 'case sensitive chosen db name');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', 'root');

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

Comment: Can you follow this tutorial to create a database. 

https://complete-concrete-concise.com/web-tools/creating-a-mysql-database-using-xampp/

Those values have to be exactly right.

Comment: You want to create a new database, making sure to remember the database name, password, and username. Then replace the values above with those from this new database.

I am 97% sure the hostname of "localhost" will be the right one. So don't worry about that one.

Answer (score 0):

in such case you can use the localhost ip like hostname 127.0.0.1:3308
Here 3308/3307 will be your xampp port